# Is there an easy way to add all private endpoint host entries to host aliases in values.yaml file for kubernetes deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks, kubernetes-pod, azure-pipelines-yaml

I know entries from hosts file can be added to pods like below

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: hostaliases-pod
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  hostAliases:
  - ip: "127.0.0.1"
    hostnames:
    - "foo.local"
    - "bar.local"
  - ip: "10.1.2.3"
    hostnames:
    - "foo.remote"
    - "bar.remote"
```

But I have around 900 IPs in my hosts file and need to add all of them to my values.yaml file.

Is there an easy way to add these to values.yaml without having to manually format each and every one of them like in the below format?

```
hostAliases:
  - ip: "127.0.0.1"
    hostnames:
    - "foo.local"
    - "bar.local"
  - ip: "10.1.2.3"
    hostnames:
    - "foo.remote"
    - "bar.remote"
```

Comment: You might ask your admin to install a DNS server so you don't have the repetitive and fragile task of replicating host entries in lots of places.  (I'd suggest not using a hosts file at all if possible.)  If the names only need to be visible within the cluster, an [ExternalName Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname) can add them to Kubernetes's internal DNS system.

Comment: It's definitely possible for a Helm chart to take a list of values and convert it to a different YAML syntax.  What do you think the input should look like?  What have you tried already?

Comment: @DavidMaze the above method in the question did not work for me. It is a spark application not sure if that makes any difference. Is there any example for what you mentioned? Helm chart to take list of values?

Comment: @DavidMaze Is there an easy way to resolve multiple hostnames in a private DNS zone? I have about 900 hostnames and Ip addresses I need to add on my private DNS zone, Should I be adding all of them manually? I checked with a couple of them and it works, the Private DNS zone returns the corresponding IP but how do I do it for a really big IP & hostname range?

Comment: You can do it with a tool like Terraform, but that sort of network-administration question is well off-topic for Stack Overflow.  Consider asking on [devops.se] or [sf].

Comment: @DavidMaze Sure will do, thanks for the suggestion. I created a private DNS zone in azure and it is working (I tested with a couple of hostnames) but I have to manually add all 900+ hostnames, hence looking for a better solution

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered creating some Service(s), pointing to that list of IPs? Might be easier to deal with, depending on the volume of containers you have to manage ...

Something like this:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: stuff-outside-of-sdn
  namespace: default
subsets:
- addresses:
  - ip: 10.0.0.1
  - ip: 10.0.0.2
  - ip: 10.0.0.3
  - ip: 10.0.0.N
  ports:
  - name: something
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: stuff-outside-of-sdn
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
  - name: something
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
```

Now, containers running in your cluster can resolve "stuff-outside-of-sdn.default.svc.local", pointing them to addresses we've defined in that Endpoints. Changing some IPs in those endpoints don't require restarting all containers / getting rid of hostAliases.

When we don't set a spec.selector to a Service, kubernetes controllers won't change endpoints, we can do pretty much anything.

Keeping in mind those Services would affect resolution for all containers in your cluster, which may not be what you wanted.

Another take on it might be to just setup some DNS server. Which again, would affect resolution for all clients. While may be easier to maintain, depending on who's administering this, ... good old DNS zones could make more sense, less constraints, allows to use a base domain distinct from k8s cluster.

... And if you need those resolution exception to be unique from deployment to deployment ... Then, the solution you have is pretty much all you can do. While obviously suffers from scaling issues. At which point, we might question: why such a workaround, any chance/how could we get rid of this?

Comment: btw adding my hostAliases like above is not working. I am running a spark application on AKS and I am still facing host name issues and I don't see these added in the hosts file as well when I bash into one of the pods